# Bootstrap card does not consistently flex to full width

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have got the following search input on my blog which works great so far using `simple-jekyll-search`. I display the results in a card with `z-index: 2;`

[image]

However when there are no search results, the card doesn't flex to the full width. I just don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

[image]

Please find bellow the relevant code. The search results are getting assigned by id `search-result` as list items.

- How can I properly use the `flex` classes here to make the "No results found" text flex to the full width?
- Where should I place the `flex-column`, `flex-sm-row` and `flex-sm-fill`?
- How do the `d-flex` classes play in here?

---

```
<nav>
    <!-- removed --> 

    <!-- Right side items -->
    <form class="navbar-nav form-inline flex-column flex-sm-row" style="flex-basis: 350px;">
      <!-- Fill on sm breakpoint -->
      <div class="input-group flex-sm-fill">
        <input class="form-control" id="search-box" type="search" placeholder="Search">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="card shadow px-4 border-top-0" id="result-box" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 49px; z-index: 2;">
          <ul class="list-unstyled" id="search-result"></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This is the javascript part:

```
<script>
  SimpleJekyllSearch({
    searchInput: document.getElementById('search-box'),
    resultsContainer: document.getElementById('search-result'),
    searchResultTemplate: `
    <li>
      <a href="{url}">
        <p><h6>{title}</h6></p>
      </a>
      <p>Category: <span class="badge badge-dark">{category}</span> Tags: <span class="badge badge-info">{tags}</span></p> 
    </li>`,
    json: '/search.json',
    noResultsText: `
    <li>
      <p><h6>No results found!</h6></p>
    </li>`
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `flex` classes here to make "No results found" to full width. In fact, the reason why that doesn't take the full width is because with absolute positioning, the element's width is set to `auto`. "No results found!" is not long enough to cover the whole width of the input group.

The fix is either to set the result box's width to 100%, or to tell the absolute positioning element where to start from the left and right, i.e., `left: 0; right: 0;`.

```html
<div class="card shadow border-top-0 result-box">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>
            <h6>NO RESULTS FOUND!</h6>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I assigned a CSS class `.result-box` so that you don't have to do the inline styling.

```css
.result-box {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;

    /* Either use 100% width, or the left right combination */
    width: 100%;

    /*left: 0;
    right: 0;*/

    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    top: 100%;
}
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/oe3hk27g/19/

Oh also I don't think you can wrap `<h6 />` with a paragraph so I changed that in my demo.

Comment: Man you are a hero! I know SO doesn't like 'thank-you-comments', but sometimes I just have to...so thanks a bunch